# Unable to upload Image to database due to Base64 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, wcf, model-view-controller

I am following a tutorial on how to upload an image to a database and then retrieve it. My WCF service, which is working fine, has a function that inserts the data into the database like so:

```
public bool CreateTeam(string userId, string teamId, string name, string coach, byte[] photo)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO t" + userId + "(Id, Name, Coach, Photo) VALUES (@id, @name, @coach, @photo)";

        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TeamsConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", teamId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coach", coach);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

            return true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + ex.Message);

            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my controller, I have a reference to the WCF Service and a `HttpPostedFileBase` to get the uploaded file like so:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Team team)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase photo = Request.Files["Photo"];

            TeamsService.ServiceClient client = new TeamsService.ServiceClient();
            client.Open();

            if (client.CreateTeam(Session["DynamixSessionId"].ToString(), team.Id, team.Name, team.Coach, ConvertToBytes(photo)))
            {
                client.Close();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Teams");
            }

            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The `ConvertToBytes` function is outlined below:

```
public byte[] ConvertToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = null;

        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
        fileBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);

        return fileBytes;
    }
```

My `Team` model is as so:

```
[Key]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This cannot be empty")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This cannot be empty")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "This cannot be empty")]
    public string Coach { get; set; }

    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

In my View, I have a form with the `enctype` attribute like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Teams", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
        <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Coach, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Coach, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Coach, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="Photo" id="Photo" />
                </div>
            </div>
}
```

When I click on the submit button, the other fields insert correctly and I can see them from my SQL Server database. As soon as I add my `Photo` field (of type `varbinary`), I get the following error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Why am I getting this error? Any suggestions on how to resolve the error?

Comment: Sorry for the large amount of code. I'm really unsure on what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You need to make sure that `Photo` is of type `HttpPostedFileBase` in order for the upload to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is your file upload control using the ID of your `Photo` field in your model? The `Photo` field must be of type `HttpPostedFileBase` in order for the image to be uploaded correctly and to avoid the `Base64` error. I suggest you make the following changes:

1. In your **model**, add the following:

   ```
   public HttpPostedFileBase UploadedPhoto { get; set; }
   ```
2. In your **view**, add the following:

   ```
   <input type="file" name="UploadedPhoto" id="UploadedPhoto" />
   ```
3. In your **controller**, add the following:

   ```
   HttpPostedFileBase photo = Request.Files["UploadedPhoto"];

   TeamsService.ServiceClient client = new TeamsService.ServiceClient();
   client.Open();

   if (client.CreateTeam(Session["DynamixSessionId"].ToString(), team.Id, team.Name, team.Coach, ConvertToBytes(photo)))
   {
       client.Close();

       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Teams");
   }

   else
   {
       return View();
   }
   ```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I want to keep `Photo` with type `byte[]` so I can display it later on.

Comment: Then keep it. Just add another field in your model as I mentioned in the first step.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is that you should specify parameter type. `commandd.Parameters.Add("@photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, LengthOfFieldOnTheServerSide).Value = photo;` This suggestion is based on my previous "fights" with SQL queries. For me it was creating query with `system.byte []` in the place of parameter instead of actual value of `byte []`.

*sorry for typos I'm using StackExchange app on my phone*

Comment: For the `LENGTHOFFIELD`, do I use `photo.ContentLength` and pass that as a parameter?

Comment: Also, my `Photo` column in my table is of type `VARBINARY(max)`. Should it be at `max` or should it be less than that?

Comment: Max is `8000` i think so put `8000` in the length

Comment: I have done what you told me but I still get the error. Should I be converting the bytes into Base64 or something?